# equals() and contains() seemingly contradict

Tags: java, collections, equality

```
            for(Context context : contexts) {

                if(context.equals(c)){
                    System.out.println(context.equals(c)+" : "+contexts.contains(c));
                }
            }
```

**contexts** is a standard java TreeSet

To me, it seems that if this produces ANY output, it should produce "true : true". Strangely, it always comes back with "true : false".

Looking at the documentation; I am in essence replicating exactly what the .contains function does, yet getting a different result.

Can anyone explain this?

EDIT: From the java documentation (Collection):

> Returns true if this collection contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this collection contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Comment: Please, provide `Context` source if it custom, or provide fully qualified name including package if it public accessible.

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev It is neither. Not sure why it should matter regardless, as it is the implementation of TreeSet that is in question.

Comment: No, what is in question is your implementation of `equals()` and your implementation of `compareTo()`.

Comment: **To me, it seems that if this produces ANY output, it should produce "true : true"** - No, it can produce "true:false" if the hashCode implementation is just bad, not matching the equals implementation and the object has been modified after adding it to the set (hence a different hashcode).

Comment: Seems like your `Context` class badly implements `equals`, you test `context.equals( c )` but `contains` tests `c.equals(context)`. `equals` must be symmetric.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Reversing the equals gives the same result.

Comment: Note from `TreeSet` documentation: _Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface._ So please provide your `compareTo`.

Comment: The real question is: why do you just put up a fraction of your code, instead of an [mcve].

Comment: @RealSkeptic I cannot. It's a piece of code I cannot see.

Comment: So test if it is consistent. Check if `c.compareTo(context)` and `context.compareTo(c)` both return 0.

Comment: `compareTo` and `equals` may be broken

Comment: @RealSkeptic They... both return 1? Okay,something is indeed wrong here. compareTo and equals certainly are being weird.

Comment: Since TreeSet is sorting elements using their natural order (if they implement `Comparable#compareTo` method), or if elements are not Comparable or we want to use different order we can use our own Comparator. Problem is that either of these comparing methods don't respect fact that if objects are equal result of comparing should be `0`. We can't say what exactly is wrong here without seeing proper [mcve].

Comment: I've reported the issue to the provider of the Context class. Meanwhile, thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that the `hashcode` implementation does not jibe with `equals`.

The `contains` method will find where the object **should** be using the `hashcode`. It will then check to see if it **is** there using `equals`.

I would suggest therefore that if you are getting `true:false` then you need to fix your `hashcode` implementation so that

*If `equals` returns `true` for two objects then `hashcode` on the two objects return the **same** value*.

With a `TreeSet` the place where the object **should** be is located using `compareTo` so do the equivalent there.

Comment: hashCode in a `TreeSet`?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: The hashcode is actually fine. Using a HashSet instead of a TreeSet I'm getting the 'normal' results.